# javascript user inputs go into the wrong part of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a carousel with questions in them. Everytime I click on an answer it adds the value of that answer to a multidimensional array. At the moment I have 3 questions with answers, but there could me more because it's dynamical. The problem is that all the question values are put in the last array, but the answers of the first question should go in the first part and the second answers should go in the second part etc.

This is what my code looks like:

```
 this.count = 0;

        Initialize() {
            for (let i = 0; i < Quiz.length; i++) {
                let question = this.SetQuestion(this.questionNumber + 1);
                let pre = question.prefix;
                let answers = question.chosenAnswer.slice(0, -1);

                let slide = document.createElement('div');
                slide.classList.add('carousel_item', "carousel_item" + i, pre);
                slide.id = 'Slide' + i;
                document.getElementById('QuizCarousel').appendChild(slide);

                for (let y = 0; y < answers.length; y++) {
                    let item = answers;
                    console.log(item[y])

                    let btn = document.createElement('button');
                    btn.value = item[y].id;
                    btn.classList.add("filter_anwser")
                    btn.id = 'answerbtn' + i;
                    btn.textContent = item[y].name;
                    document.getElementsByClassName("carousel_item" + i)[0].appendChild(btn);
                }
        }

        next(){
            this.IntoArray()
            console.log(this.LinkChecker(this.getLink()))
            this.count++;
            console.log(this.url);
            console.log(this.count)
        }

        previous(){
            this.IntoArray()
            console.log(this.LinkChecker(this.getLink()))
            this.count--;
        }

        IntoArray() {
            const UrlVar = new URLSearchParams(this.getLink())
            this.UrlArray = [...UrlVar.entries()].map(([key, values]) => (
                    {[key]: values.split(",")}
                )
            );
        }

        /**
         * Returns the parameters for the URL.
         *
         * @returns {string}
         */
        getLink() {
            this.tmp = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                // Check if question is from the same quiz part and adds a , between chosen answers and add the right prefix at the beginning
                if (this.url[i].length > 0) {
                    this.tmp.push("" + Quiz[i].prefix + this.url[i].join(","))
                }
                // if the link is empty remove everything that was added (& an ,)
                if (this.url[i].length === 0) {
                    this.tmp.push("");
                }
            }
            /// If answers are from different quiz parts add a & between answers
            return "" + this.tmp.join("&");
        };
```

The problem lies in the for loop in GetLink(), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it right.

This is what the console look like now when I log this.url

```
(3) [Array(0), Array(0), Array(3)]
0: []
1: []
2: (4) ['6621', '6056', '6048', '5805']
length: 3
```

Everything goes into the last array, but it shouldn't.

See the console and code for yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/thijsl0705/Lxqoa1pb/5/

Comment: You set `this.tmp = [];` then you have a set of conditionals to push to that. But you have `// if the link is empty remove everything that was added (& an ,)` as a comment but that next conditional removes nothing, it just pushed an  empty string.  Otherwise you do nothing - SO we can only guess why the last loop pushes but not the others - we cannot guess here what is in `this.url[i]`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Well this part of the code works, but at first the questions where one by one generated so at first this.url was 1 and when next was pressed the array length was 2 and so on. this.url[i] was 1, 2 and 3 but now everything is generated at ones so it's always number 3. and the remove part just empties the array only when nothing is clicked

Comment: Line 282: No matter what I do, `control.questionNumber` is always 2, and `control.url.length` is always 3. Therefore you never clear the array and always push into `control.url[control.questionNumber]` the third array index.

Comment: @clash I know it's always 3 and I have been trying to make it a different way so it's counts up as you go through the questions, but I can't find any. Do you know a way?

Comment: Increment it. You set it to -1 in `constructor`, you increment it +1 in `Initialize` and overwrite it when setting a new Question. This by itself seems a little jiffy. But other than that, you never do anything to it. So of course by the end of adding all Questions, it will be at the last Question index. It seems you don't really want `questionNumber`, but `this.count`, since you in- and decrement it in `next` and `prev`.

Comment: Also, maybe think about structuring answers as well. You have classes for the question-part, but the answers logic is just an eventListener.